# Default clause before case sections in the switch statement

Tags: c, switch-statement

Found this in linux/kernel/signal.c

```
switch (_NSIG_WORDS) {
default:
    for (i = 1; i < _NSIG_WORDS; ++i) {
        x = *++s &~ *++m;
        if (!x)
            continue;
        sig = ffz(~x) + i*_NSIG_BPW + 1;
        break;
    }
    break;

case 2:
    x = s[1] &~ m[1];
    if (!x)
        break;
    sig = ffz(~x) + _NSIG_BPW + 1;
    break;

case 1:
    /* Nothing to do */
    break;
}
```

Maybe this is not quite good example, but I can't understand how it works and what prompted Linus to put default-section at front of the switch statement.

Comment: `x = *++s &~ *++m;` == `x = (*(++s)) & (~(*(++m)));`..`default:` is like any other case if you don't write as last you need to add `break;` statement for same reason we  other case

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The order of `case` labels within a `switch` block in the code has nothing to do with which one is executed.  The `default` label is executed if no `case` matches or it falls through from a `case` above it.  Having it first in the code base doesn't change this.

The one advantage to having `default` be first is that it's impossible for a `case` above it to accidentally or intentionally fall through to `default`.  This means `default` will run if, and only if, the value matches no `case` statements in the `switch` block.

To be extremely pedantic you could still hit the `default` label with an explicit `goto`.  That is pretty rare though.

Comment: Not sure if I quite get the reasoning for the second part of the answer. The assumption being that it is more dangerous to fall through to default than any other case?

Comment: @Ziffusion the reasoning is as follows: People believe that `default` should only be hit if there is no matching value. Putting it at the top makes visually easier to validate this is indeed the case. It also makes future additions which do fall through and violate the assumption about `default` much more visible. Note I'm not saying I agree with it, this is simply the logic others have presented to me in the past

Comment: Thank you so much, @JaredPar, I thought that swith-case works like `if('a'){/*something*/}else if('b'){/*something else*/} else{/*quite another*/}`, and `default` clause is something like the last `else` without `if(...)`. I think this is an important aspect of the C language, so thank you again.